# What Codec Shows Absolute Black?

Tags: codec, color-correction, compression

I need a codec that outputs an absolute black.
Encoded some samples with .AVI no compression and the black background of my video is very dark. Contrary in other codecs like Apple ProRes or H264/MPEG4 the black background of the same video is dark gray.
Is there a codec that can show the same black that the uncompressed .AVI has?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Vantolinomo - You might just be experiencing 'gamma shift' which can happen when you are exporting to H264 video.  You can find a tutorial to fix this here:

http://www.videocopilot.net/blog/2008/06/fix-quicktime-gamma-shift/